# Unable to start spark-shell in windows

Tags: apache-spark

**I'm new to spark and cannot start it in the command prompt by typing spark-shell as it gives me the following lines:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2464)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2464)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2464)
        at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.secMgr$lzycompute$1(SparkSubmit.scala:393)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$secMgr$1(SparkSubmit.scala:393)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:401)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:401)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:400)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:52)
        ... 21 more
```

**Please help.**

**P.S. Followed this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlE7RNdtfwE with the only changes being that I got all the newest versions of the softwares.**

Comment: Please add more details like version of java, spark, scala, and how did run ?

Comment: Java-jdk10 Spark-2.3.0 Hadoop-2.7 Scala-4.7.0

Comment: Please use jdk 1.8 and spark 2.11.8, spark 2.3 is ok. I don't there is scala version with 4.7.0

Answer (score 3):

Try not to use all the latest versions, Use most stable versions.

As the time of this answer, I suggest you use

1. `Java/JDK     -> 1.8`
2. `Scala        -> 2.11.8`
3. `Apache Spark -> Spark-2.3.0 Hadoop-2.7`

I hope this solves your problem too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just changing the jdk kit worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. If you have multiple JDKs installed, you can set JDK1.8 path in spark-env.sh file like this: ```JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_181"```